# adding up numbers after an if operation in R

Tags: r, countif

I have a set of data which consists of the number of courses of medication that a patient has taken at a certain date.

```
subject<-c(111,111,111,222,222,333,333,333,333)
date<-as.Date(c("2010-12-12","2011-12-01","2009-8-7","2010-5-7","2011-3-7","2011-8-5","2013-8-27","2016-9-3","2011-8-5"))
medicationCourses<-c(1,0,NA,3,4,2,4,5,6)

data<-data.frame(subject,date,medicationCourses)

data

  subject      date        medicationCourses
1     111    2010-12-12             1
2     111    2011-12-01             0
3     111    2009-08-07             NA
4     222    2010-05-07             3
5     222    2011-03-07             4
6     333    2011-08-05             2
7     333    2013-08-27             4
8     333    2016-09-03             5
9     333    2011-08-05             6
```

I also have their hospital admission date.

```
hospitalSubject<-c(111,222,333)
admissionDate<-as.Date(c("2011-12-31","2013-12-31","2013-12-31"))

hospitalData<-data.frame(hospitalSubject,admissionDate)

hospitalData

  hospitalSubject admissionDate
1             111    2011-12-31
2             222    2013-12-31
3             333    2013-12-31
```

I want to summarise the number of medication courses on or before the admission date and to produce the following outcome:

```
subject    admissionDate   totalMedicationCourses
 111         2011-12-31            1
 222         2013-12-31            7
 333         2013-12-31            12
```

I wonder if anyone could let me know how I could do this in R?  I am a novice user of R so any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to `merge` the two datasets by `subject/hospitalSubject` in the two datasets, `subset` the rows with `date <= admissionDate`, and get the `sum` of 'medicationCourses' grouped by 'subject/admissionDate' with `aggregate`

```
d1 <- subset(merge(data, hospitalData, by.x='subject', 
           by.y='hospitalSubject'), date <= admissionDate)

aggregate(medicationCourses~subject+admissionDate, d1, sum,
               na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
#  subject admissionDate medicationCourses
#1     111    2011-12-31                 1
#2     222    2013-12-31                 7
#3     333    2013-12-31                12
```

Or we can use `data.table` by converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), set the key as 'subject' (`setkey(`), and join with `hospitalData`, filter the rows where `date <= admissionDate` and get the `sum` of 'medicationCourses', grouped by 'subject' and 'admissionDate'.

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(data), subject)[hospitalData][date <= admissionDate, 
  list(TotalMedicationCourses=sum(medicationCourses, na.rm=TRUE)),
        list(subject, admissionDate)]
#    subject admissionDate TotalMedicationCourses
#1:     111    2011-12-31                      1
#2:     222    2013-12-31                      7
#3:     333    2013-12-31                     12
```

Or a similar approach with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
  left_join(data, hospitalData, by=c('subject'='hospitalSubject')) %>%
        filter(date <=admissionDate) %>% 
        group_by(subject, admissionDate) %>% 
        summarise(TotalMedicationCourses=sum(medicationCourses, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you SO much.  And thanks to the other user who posted a reply but deleted it a few mins ago.  They are all very helpful!!!